# Allow duplicate rows in SQL only when another column of the same table has a certain value

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following schema:

```
create table dummy 
(
   id int primary key auto_increment,
   reference_id string not null,
   status enum('CREATED','FAILED','SUCCESS','RETRY') default 'CREATED',
   customId string unique not null
);
```

`reference_id` column is supposed to be unique all the time other than it should only allow duplicate values when the previous row with same `reference_id` has `status` as `FAILED`. Insertion in table is done through rest API written in NestJS. While insertion, `status` is set to `CREATED`.

I want to check two possibly faulty conditions:

1. When two simultaneous API hits are received with same data, only one record should get inserted and other should fail since both have same `reference_id`.
2. When previous record of `reference_id` has status `FAILED`, only then new record with same reference_id should be allowed to be inserted.

I have given a thought of using trigger just before insertion to check for reference_id with status FAILED, but is there a better way to handle it in SQL DB?

Comment: Please don't spam tag rdbms - tag a single one!

Comment: By bother storing a `reference_id` with `FAILED`. Can't only one REST call be succesful?

Comment: @danblack No, there is some async processing happening after the insertion of the row and there are chances that the processing gets `FAILED`

Comment: What means "previous record" - is it any existing record with same reference_id? Can same reference_id have multiple FAILED rows? In MS SQL Server I would use trigger.

Comment: On SQL Server you can use a filtere unique index `INDEX IX UNIQUE (reference_id) WHERE (status <> 'FAILED')`

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB example with the table structure:

```
create table dummy (
   id int primary key auto_increment,
   reference_id varchar(30) not null,
   status enum('CREATED','FAILED','SUCCESS','RETRY') default 'CREATED',
   customId varchar(30) unique not null,
   statusR int AS (if(status='FAILED', NULL, 1)),
   unique key rs (reference_id,statusR)
);
```

As `reference_id` isn't a full unique criteria, multiple failed are allowed.

We use the property that `NULL` doesn't match `NULL` so that there is an unlimited number of `reference_id` with a `statusR` as `null`.  `statusR` is a generated column. If status is anything other than `FAILED`, 1 is returned making the `unique key rs` can only have one non-`FAILED`, `reference_id`.

The multiple insert of a the same `reference_id`, one will hit a duplicate key error, process is in the application an follow up with an insert of `reference_id`,`FAILED` which will succeed.

ref: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vfXo_-eZ)